# Copying dependencies into local repo as a Jar and including the Jar as classpath using appassembler-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, tomcat, heroku

I'm using latest version of Maven, and earlier I was trying to include a particular dependency (call it dependency `A`) into a multi-module project (Java Web App using Tomcat and another Java project) in Windows by testing it locally, and create the normal Java project to be runnable using a `.bat` script using the [Appasembler plugin `appasemble` command](http://www.mojohaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/assemble-mojo.html) in my POM. But it turns out dependency `A` has a lot of dependencies it include, and the `.bat` script generated exceeds the length limit it can execute due to lots of classpath being included.
So I decided to package it inside a jar, and reference all libraries in a single jar from a single place and exclude the existing classpaths by using the `maven-dependency-plugin` and `copy` goal :

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version> 
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                      <!--Below this is the dependency `A` -->
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
                                <artifactId>deeplearning4j-nlp</artifactId>
                                <version>${dl4j.version}</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                      <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/localrepo</outputDirectory>

                                <destFileName>deeplearninglib</destFileName>

                            </artifactItem>

                        </artifactItems>

                        <localRepositoryDirectory>${project.basedir}\localrepo</localRepositoryDirectory>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

It successfully created the jar with all its dependencies. Now I'm trying to include the jar into my classpath generated in my `.bat` script, but when I take a look at `appassembler:assemble` documentation, there's no such command to exclude the existing classpaths that are already in new jar and including the newly packaged jar to the `.bat` script.
So is there any way I can include newly packaged jar as classpath and exclude the classpaths that are already included in the newly pacakaged jar from the launchable `.bat` script?

**EDIT** : As a temporary fix, I managed to fix the long classpath issue by using wildcards and flattening the directory layout by including :

```
 <repositoryLayout>flat</repositoryLayout>
 <useWildcardClassPath>true</useWildcardClassPath>
```

to the `appassembler` plugin. However, the question still remains open as this has still not answered the main question.

Comment: If you already use the option `useWildcardClassPath` which is available since Java 6...I'm honestly not able to understand what your problem is?

Comment: @khmarbaise Previously I was trying to shorten the classpath length in `bat` script and I didn't know the existence of `useWildcardClassPath` command, so I was trying to create a jar that contains all the third-party dependencies (including dependency `A` as explained above), and add that particular jar as classpath to the `bat` script instead of adding each individual classpath of the dependencies to the `bat` script. However, I'm also still interested in knowing how to fully implement my original approach (without using `useWildcardClassPath`), and whether if it's possible.